# Type matching with instance of Type in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, types

While I can do the following:

```
void main() {
  print(42 is ArgumentError);
}
```

the following example does not work:

```
void main() {
  Type type = ArgumentError;
  
  print(42 is type);
}
```

because static analysis complains `The name 'type' isn't a type and can't be used in an 'is' expression.`.

Similar to the above minimal example I cannot build an `isA<>()` matcher in flutter test to do a type check as in

```
    test("", () {
      Type type = ArgumentError;
      
      expect(42, isA<type>());
    });
```

Is there a workaround for this to perform a typecheck with an instance of Type instead of a type literal (is this the right expression? :) )? Or is this a no-no because dart does not support reflection?

Comment: You really can't do much with a Type in a variable.  They're just compile-time constants.

Comment: At best you can do `42.runtimeType == type`, but note that it will check for *exact* types, so `42.runtimeType == num` will not work (can't check for subtypes), nor will `<int>[].runtimeType == List` (`List<int>` is not identical to `List<dynamic>`), nor will `<String, int>{}.runtimeType == Map<String, int>` (`Map` is an abstract class, so the concrete runtime type always will be something else).